# -avas- AVAudioSessionPortImpl... message-flood in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

While using `Xcode` (Version 10.1) and `Swift` (4.2), my debugging console gets flooded with messages like the ones below.
Searching the net shows that I am not the only one to experience this. But I did not find any solution.

Beside I need to say that the iOS app I am working on when getting that has nothing to do with audio and does not use anything related to audio, making it even less understandable why I get this kind of messages.

Does anyone knows how to get rid of that?

```
2019-01-02 18:21:35.507678+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:21:35.904813+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:21:36.287815+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:21:36.662213+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:22:44.924605+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:22:45.556019+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:22:45.560240+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
...........
2019-01-02 18:22:45.984256+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:22:46.373893+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:22:46.797403+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:22:47.086722+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:23:55.484442+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
...........
2019-01-02 18:23:56.431874+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
2019-01-02 18:23:56.437379+0900 XYZ[3930:837626] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port スピーカー (type: Speaker)
```

Comment: Are you using any third party APIs (such as turn by turn navigation) that could have an option to provide audio feedback? From what I've read AVAudioSession had some syntax changes recently. Could be that some code needs updating, possibly by third party devs?

Comment: Well, I am using a few pods like SwiftSoup, Firebase/xxx. That's all I can say.